# HTML how to make each row of a table scrollable?

Tags: html, css

I have a table, I want to give css "overflow:scroll" to each tr, but its not working. Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>hai</td>
    <td>hellow</td>
    <td>shcjbjs</td>
    <td>dvkd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>hai</td>
    <td>hellow</td>
    <td>shcjbjs</td>
    <td>dvkd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>hai</td>
    <td>hellow</td>
    <td>shcjbjs</td>
    <td>dvkd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>hai</td>
    <td>hellow</td>
    <td>shcjbjs</td>
    <td>dvkd</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table{
border:1px solid red;
}
td{
  border:1px solid blue;
  height:100px;
}
tr{
  height:50px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

I have made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E2r2W/) with the example please give me a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check this working demo** **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/E2r2W/6/)**

```
table{
    border:1px solid red;
}
td{
    border:1px solid blue;
    height:100px;
}
tr{
    height:50px;
    overflow:scroll;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try `overflow:scroll;` in td

Answer (score 0):

You may try CSS properties:

```
overflow: scroll;
```

or

```
overflow: auto;
```

Similarly, you may also use:

```
`overflow-y` if you want only a vertical scroll or
`overflow-x` if you want only a horizontal scroll
```

> Do set a `height` for the row and check browser compatibility for all these CSS properties.
>
> Use a set of `div` instead of a table for better results

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
  <td>your long content here</td>
</tr>
```

css:

```
tr{
    height:50px;
    display:block;
    overflow-y:auto;overflow-x: hidden;    
}
```

FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/kemalemin/E2r2W/7/

Comment: I guess he wants it on tr and not td,scroll on td will work directly without adding <div>

Comment: @Emin but i need a scroll over tr

Answer (score 0):

```
table{
    border:1px solid red;
}
td{
    border:1px solid blue;
    height:100px;
}
tr{
    height:50px;
    overflow:scroll;
    display:block;
}
```

this might help, but i am not sure if this is any way of treating the table...